# Когда тире трудно отличить от двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Правила правилами, но вот в предложениях примерно одинаковой структуры при наличии одного и того же слова, требующего пояснения, ставится **и двоеточие, и тире.** Можно ли это как-то объяснить, или это ничем не обоснованный  авторский выбор?

(1) **Одно** было в нём нехорошо: ужасно падок был на деньги. [М. Ю. Лермонтов. Герой нашего времени (1839-1841)]

(2) **Одно** в нем было скверно: ни одного лакея он не звал по имени, но для каждого имел свой свист. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Пошехонская старина. Житие Никанора Затрапезного, пошехонского дворянина (1887-1889)]

(3) **Одно** в нем не нравилось товарищам ― какое-то преувеличенное, экзотическое женолюбие. [А. И. Куприн. Яма (1909-1915)]

(4) Непонятно было **одно** ― как далеко от оконного проема расположено создающее мираж оборудование. [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)]

(5) Она ничего не поняла, но ясно было **одно** ― ее помиловали, и жизнь продолжается. [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Правила правилами, но вот в предложениях примерно одинаковой структуры
>   при наличии одного и того же слова, требующего пояснения, ставится **и
>   двоеточие, и тире.** Можно ли это как-то объяснить, или это ничем не
>   обоснованный авторский выбор?

Ну, если бы тире вместо традиционного двоеточия употребляло бы ограниченное число авторов, это можно было бы назвать авторской пунктуацией. А так…

Вот что пишет по этому поводу  **Валгина Н.С.**  в книге [**"Актуальные  проблемы современной русской пунктуации"**](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/valgina.aktualnuye_ptobl_rus_punkt.2004.259_%28sl%29.htm#_Toc332949565) (М., 2004):

> Может случиться, что какие-либо отклонения от правил окажутся в
>   сочинениях того или иного автора и они могут быть восприняты как
>   индивидуально-авторские, в то время как таковыми фактически не
>   являются. Например, **в современной печати все чаще в новых
>   синтаксических условиях употребляется тире (на месте двоеточия):**
>   между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения при обозначении
>   пояснения, причины во второй части, при обобщающих словах перед
>   перечислением однородных членов и т.п.
>
> Например: *Мне довелось беседовать со многими из них   —   и
>   ровесниками Шапошникова, и сменой годами помоложе* (Правда. 1986. 11
>   сентября.); *Под развесистой кроной не бывает пусто   —   отдыхают
>   путники, чабаны, благо, живительный родник рядом* (Правда. 1986. 11
>   сент.); *Сюда прибыли 16 тысяч механизаторов   —   из России, с
>   Украины, из Прибалтики, республик Средней Азии* (Правда. 1986. 10
>   сент.).
>
> Схожее употребление знаков найдем и у писателей, поэтов…
>
> **Такие отклонения от правил**  [речь в книге шла о Правилах-56; в вышедшем впоследствии ПАС правила уточнены] **отражают общие современные тенденции в
>   развитии пунктуации и к авторской индивидуальности не имеют отношения.
>   Они постепенно готовят почву для изменения или уточнения самих правил.**

И ещё:

> Употребление двоеточия сводится к очень конкретным и явно
>   немногочисленным конструкциям, особенно закрепляется оно в позиции
>   перед перечислением (хотя и здесь тире уже достаточно потеснило
>   двоеточие). **В других же случаях <...> двоеточие практически заменяется
>   тире...**
>
> Практика такого широкого употребления тире вместо двоеточия (а иногда
>   и запятой) отнюдь не свидетельствует о том, что в тех же условиях уже
>   не может стоять обычный знак: параллельное употребление
>   свидетельствует лишь о наметившейся тенденции и, следовательно, в
>   данное время о возможности выбора знака  —  более традиционного,
>   строгого, 'академического' (двоеточия) и нового, более вольного,
>   энергичного и экспрессивного (тире). Выбор зависит от характера
>   текста, манеры изложения, наконец, от авторской привычки, но **ясно одно
>   —  сдержать наступательное движение тире уже нельзя.**

Comment: С точки зрения интонации, употребление тире на месте классического двоеточия обозначает нежелание автора делать увеличенную паузу, предупреждающую о последующем пояснении, что в свою очередь связано с характером текста, манерой изложения и т. д. Таким образом мы переходим от пояснительной конструкции к присоединительной, где не указывается направление (например, причина-следствие или следствие-причина), а просто обозначается взаимообусловленность предложений.

Comment: Обязательное двоеточие, как мне кажется,  нужно в сложном (или осложненном  предложении), чтобы, к примеру,  указать, что пояснение относится к двум/трем предложениям, то есть при распространенности поясняющей части.

Answer (score 1):

Ясно одно: двоеточие постепенно отступает под натиском тире.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, Вы правы. Тире - универсальный знак, долгих размышлений не требует. Скоро от всех правил останется их  очень маленькая часть, а именно два случая: а) пишется только тире, запрещается двоеточие; б) пишется только двоеточие, запрещается тире.